# What is the surface area of the cardiovascular system?

Tags: blood-circulation, circulatory-system

[In this question says:](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15582/are-there-60-000-miles-of-blood-vessels-in-the-human-body)

> An adult human has been estimated to have some 60,000 miles (96,560
>   km) of capillaries with a total surface area of some 800–1000 m2 (an
>   area greater than three tennis courts).

But the question is about the length and only mentions area in the body not the title, and the answers don't cite the area.

Comment: Does the Coastline paradox affect this?

Comment: Friction? Drag in blood vessels is much more complex than friction...

Comment: @Aron Ok, but maybe I can calculate a lower bound.

Comment: @Andrey Very interesting point. To that I can answer this: imagine a blood vessel section of 0.1 meter long, and 0.01 meter in "average diameter" (that needs to be estimated. Then you say the surface area corresponding of that section of the circulatory system is the area of the abstract cilinder we use to represent it. Also, [if we specify the ruler size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox), the area becomes more well defined (althought still subjective a little).

Comment: Friction is a very bad word to describe it. But the simplest way to estimate the drag is to use Newton's 3rd. The drag is equal to the force on the blood, assuming the blood is at a steady speed. Figure out how hard the heart pushes.

Comment: @Aron I edited out the friction part, it wasn't part of the "question part" of the question. Indeed, it was why the doubt arised but not the doubt itself. Now the question is simpler. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Santropedro so what is your question? Are you asking if the area estimation is correct?

Comment: @MattDMo Now the title make it obvious, the question is how much meters squared of surface does the circulatory system posses.

Comment: Even that is a difficult question to answer. It really can only be answered with "it depends on what you are asking".

Comment: @Aron To wich comment are you answering? I don't understand why it depends on what I'm asking, I'm clearly asking one specific thing. There is no variables that can't be handled in the answer that I see, if there are tell me what they are. I don't understand where the ambiguity is for you, explain please. The cardiovascualr system is a well defined closed system, and a vein for example in wich blood circulates, has a certain shape wich can be asbtractly treated as a tube cilindrically shaped that is curved, with a certain diameter.

Comment: See the first comment...the coast line paradox.